# The layout is a bit broken when react css hover is applied

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to display a border when I hover box1.
When I hover, the border is displayed, but for a moment, a black border is displayed.
Also, when I hover, the layout shifts to the bottom.
If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sunset-3fedp?file=/src/App.tsx:0-796)

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Box = styled.div`
  padding: 9px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222426;
  &:hover {
    border: solid #e2e6ea 1px;
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.08, 0.52, 0.52, 1);
  }
  span {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #222426;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
      <Box>
        <span>box1</span>
      </Box>
      <div>
        <span>aaaaaaa</span>
      </div>
      <div style={{ width: "full", height: "100px", background: "red" }}></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can set `box-sizing: border-box;`
Then set your span's height then it won't shift to the bottom.
The alternative way is making a white border, and change its color when hover.

Answer (score 0):

1. I found you have "transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.08, 0.52, 0.52, 1);" This actually causes the black border flicked for a second. If you remove it, the black border will be gone. However, I am not sure what effect do you want to achieve here.
2. If you add a border with the same background colour and same thickness inside the div i.e border: solid #fff 1px;
   The div will not push other component downward anymore.